# Search function not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, phpmyadmin

I have a form, where user can register their personal information for a club,and it will be stored in the database. Everything is working fine including MySQL.
But, I am having problem with the search function. The search page should be sticky form.
The user should be able to search and display the result...Like if they type first name or last name in the search box..then the result display all the information from the database,that meets the certain condition
 Can anyone help me to fix my search function all the page codes are given below.... 
Thank you!!!

This is my form page code.....

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
body
{
    background-color:#39B3A7;
}
</style>

<?php
global $fname,$lname,$age,$gender,$course,$email;

if(!empty($_POST['register']))
{

    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $course=$_POST['course'];
    $email=$_POST['email']; 

        if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $_POST['fname']))  {
            $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
        }
         else 
        {
        echo '<p>The First name is empty or has illegal characters! To edit please go the link Display Data Information</p>';
        $error = true;
        }


        if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $_POST['lname']))  {
            $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
        }
         else 
        {
        echo '<p>The last name is empty or has illegal characters! To edit please go the link Display Data Information</p>';
        $error = true;
        }


        if(isset($_POST['age']))
        {
            $age=$_POST['age'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>Please enter your age</p>";
        }


        if(isset($_POST['gender']))
        {   
            $gender = $_POST['gender']; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>No gender found! So, we assume you are SHEMALE</p>";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['course']))
        {
             $course = $_POST['course'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>Please Select Course!</p>";

        }

        // Validate the email:
    if (preg_match("/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['email'] )){
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }
    else 
    {
    echo '<p>The email is empty or has illegal characters! To edit please go the link Display Data Information</p>';
    $error = true;
    }
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";



}

    if($fname&&$lname&&$age&&$gender&&$course&&$email)
    {
    require_once('connection.php');
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members SET FirstName='$fname', LastName='$lname', Gender='$gender', Age='$age',          Email='$email', Course='$course'") or die(mysql_error());

        if($query){
            echo"Your Data Successfully Saved"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Please recheck your Data!";
        }


}


?>
</head>

<body>
<h2><strong>Register Student Account</strong></h2>
<form action="student_form.php" method="post" >
<table border="1">


  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname"  size="30" maxlength="50"/></td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" size="30" maxlength="50"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="age"  size="3" /></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td >Gender </td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>

    Female
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/></td>

  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Course</td>
    <td valign="top"> : </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" name="course" value="Bachelor Of Computing"/>Bachelor Of Computing<br/>
   <input type="radio" name="course" value="Bachelor Of Science"/>Bachelor Of Science<br/> 
   <input type="radio" name="course" value="Bachelor Of Software Engineering"/>Bachelor Of Software Engineering<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="Bachelor Of Networking"/>Bachelor Of Networking<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="Bacelor Of IT"/>Bacelor Of IT <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="Bachelor Of Computer Science"/>Bachelor Of Computer Science</td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>Email Address</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"  size="30" maxlength="50"/></td>
</tr>


</table>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="REGISTER"/>

</form><br>
<p><a href="student_form.php" >Home</a></p>
<p><a href="display_data.php">Display Data Information</a>
<p><a href="search.php">To search for Members</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my connection page code....

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$con = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());

$db=mysql_select_db("taylor");


?>
```

This is my display_data code....

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;   
}
body
{
    background-color:#39B3A7;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Email</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  <th>Course</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  include('connection.php');
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $rows['FirstName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['LastName']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $rows['Email']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['Age']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['Gender']; ?></td>


    <td><?php echo $rows['Course']; ?></td>
      <td>
      <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $rows['Id']; ?>">Edit</a>
      <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $rows['Id']; ?>">Delete</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</table>
<p><a href="student_form.php">Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my

This is my search page code....

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
//require_once('student_form.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$id=$_REQUEST['id']; 
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
    //connect  to the database 
include('connection.php');
//-query  the database table 
$sql="SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName=" . $fname; 
    //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
                $fname=$row['FirstName']; 
                $lname=$row['LastName']; 
                $email=$row['Email'];
                $age =$row['Age'];
                $gender=$row['Gender'];
                $course = $row['Course'];

    //-display  the result of the array 
    echo  "<ul>\n"; 
    echo  "<li>" . $fname . " " . $lname .  "</li>\n"; 
    echo  "<li>" . $email . "</li>\n";
    echo  "<li>" . $age . "</li>\n";
    echo  "<li>" . $gender . "</li>\n";
    echo  "<li>" . $course . "</li>\n"; 

    echo  "</ul>"; 
    } 
} 
?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><strong>search box</strong></td>
    <td><strong>:</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="search" value="Enter First Name of The member"size="30"/><input type="submit" value="Search"/></td>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have not given my edit and delete codes..because ..I think it is not required

Comment: having problem with the search function But what the Problem you facing ? [:-(]

Comment: 1. $sql="SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName=" . $fname; => only match a full firstname, if its a search you may want to use like and include more fields then just firstname. 2. you have an echo  "</ul>"; inside your <head>-tag, thats not the correct place to have it

Comment: who is going to scan all code?? please tell us where is problem and remove un-wanted code

Comment: when i enter any name in the search box..nothing displays

Comment: I gave all the codes, because, if someone is facing any problem in the future... they can come and refer from here...and all the codes are working codes for creating a user registration form.

Comment: @MushfiqurRahman Please include the specific error you are getting and the specific relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: An FYI you are susceptible to SQL injection (http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Please use mysql_real_escape_string http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php on fname also, think about upgrading to PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: The error is, when i enter any name in the search box..nothing displays

Comment: @MushfiqurRahman - re "we assume you are SHEMALE". Believe it or not, not everyone wishes to fit into binary [gender models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity). The, ahem, interesting sites you've been using on the interwebs are not as educational as Wikipedia!

Comment: this user registration form, I made it for my practice.. Because..I am learning php...and stuck in a specific part...if cannot help a person...itz better not mentioning some jokes that are in the form..

Comment: @halfer, why are you so rude with the op? Mushfiqur Rahman, no offence but it's not a miracle you have bugs... You should separate PHP from HTML as much as possible...

Comment: @LajosArpad - I'm one of the more patient ones here, believe it or not `:)`. But every now and again we get casual racism, sexism and (as here) gender ignorance, and it needs to be spoken to every time it comes up.

Comment: @halfer, I'm here to read programming questions/answers and to help other people with programming issues. I don't want to see here any politics or agression. If I want to read about those I open a newspaper.

Comment: @LajosArpad - I've made my case perfectly well; let's agree to disagree.

Comment: "we assume you are SHEMALE" this was rude. I agree to disagree but I don't accept rudeness.

Comment: @LajosArpad - no, read the source code. Those were the OP's words, not mine. And yes, I agree it is an unpleasant sentiment, which is why I raised it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the source code of the op was funny, but in a bad way, it's rude to some people. I'm also "gender ignorant" but would never hurt anybody because I'm ignorant and I think there are only boys and girls.

Comment: How is all of the code even relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to search, you need to use the `LIKE` syntax, not `WHERE`

```
$sql="SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%'";
```

The `LIKE & %` make it a wildcard. Now you said you want to search by first and last, but you only pass in your first variable and you only query the first field, so you will need to pass the last name as well and add an OR to the SQL and encapsulate the firstname like or lastname like in parenthesis for better performance if you expand the sql later..

```
$sql="SELECT  * FROM members WHERE (FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%' OR LastName LIKE '". $lname ."%')";
```

Comment: this one helped also THank u!! :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I agree with the other post too however, at some point you need to escape the strings either with addslashes(stripslashes()) or mysql_real_escape_string() functions, but it needs escaped for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

```
"SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName='" . $fname."'";
```

Your string should be enclosed in a quote when you do your query.

Comment: `"SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName = '$fname'";` is fine too.

Comment: Except that fname should be escaped with mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sql=""SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName = '$fname'";
```

it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this, knowing that The `LIKE & %` make it a wildcard.

```
 $sql="SELECT  * FROM members WHERE (FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%' OR LastName LIKE '". $lname ."%')";
```