# PHP&MySQL search does not work?

Tags: php, mysql, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP, MySQL validation malfunction and search doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293712/php-mysql-validation-malfunction-and-search-doesnt-work)

I have created a form, every thing is working fine, except the search. For example whenever a user input any value in the search box, it will display the result from the database, example name of the employee and etc...
Please see my coding below...

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
//require_once('student_form.php');
if(isset($_POST['search'])){ 
$id=$_REQUEST['id']; 
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
    //connect  to the database 
include('connection.php');
//-query  the database table 
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM members WHERE (FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%' OR LastName LIKE '". $lname ."%'");
    //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
                $fname=$row['FirstName']; 
                $lname=$row['LastName']; 
                /*$email=$row['Email'];
                $age =$row['Age'];
                $gender=$row['Gender'];
                $course = $row['Course'];*/
    }
    //-display  the result of the array 
    else
    {
    <?php echo $rows['FirstName']; ?>
    <?php echo $rows['LastName']; ?>
    } 
} 
?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><strong>search box</strong></td>
    <td><strong>:</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="search" value=""size="30"/><input type="submit" name="s1" value="Search"/></td>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend not to use `LIKE` statement in searching. Here's why ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478472/sql-full-text-search-vs-like

Comment: _*cringe*_ Watch out for SQL injection. At very least, use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) around `$fname` and `$lname`. But better yet, use a prepared statement with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead of using the old mysql extension.

Comment: A dup of [your question an hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293712/php-mysql-validation-malfunction-and-search-doesnt-work) which in turn is very similar to [your question before that, on 27 June](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227038/search-function-not-working-in-php)?

Comment: because I m stuck in search function, and I think it this is a helping site @halfer.

Comment: Indeed to both, but you need to be aware of widely-understood _netiquette_, which frowns upon the repeated asking of the same question. It's somewhat related to _cross-posting_; either way, you are asking several people to make the same duplicate effort for you.

Comment: And to add to the comments made by @halfer - most your your issues can easily be resolved with just a little reading / research - the PHP docs are very extensive ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that using the old `mysql_` extensions are being deprecated ... see the notice at the [top of the `mysql_query` doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also MySQL: [choosing an API guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - mysqli_query()
> - PDO::query()

But for you to see what the problem is, replace this line :

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM members WHERE (FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%' OR LastName LIKE '". $lname ."%'");
//-run  the query against the mysql query function 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

with this :

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM members WHERE (FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%' OR LastName LIKE '". $lname ."%'");
if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
```

You only need to execute `mysql_query` once and this will now output the error with your query ... as `mysql_query` returns a `boolean false` if the query fails ... [see the docs here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

And please, please take some time to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

**Note** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11294851/572939) will fix your problem - but just fixing it wont help you in the future ....

Answer (score 1):

You have to completely rewrite your code.

Firstly, remove the bracket before `FirstName` from your query:

```
"SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%' OR LastName LIKE '". $lname ."%'"
```

Now, pay attention to this: If `$sql` is the function `mysql_query`, then `$result` is running a query of query (`mysql_query(mysql_query("..."))`).

Instead, use `$result = mysql_query("...")`  and delete the variable `$sql`.

The third problem here is that you have a `<?php` tag inside your PHP code. Remove the `<?php` and `?>` tags inside `else{ }`.

I don't understand what is `$rows`, there is now declaration for this.

Comment: Thanks I was also thinking that

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the bracket near `FirstName` of this,

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM members WHERE FirstName LIKE '". $fname ."%' OR LastName LIKE '". $lname ."%'");
```